# dplyr summarise() and summarise_each() make extra calls to the provided functions

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems that `summarise` and `summarise_each` are making unnecessary extra calls to the callback functions they are provided with. Suppose that we have the following

```
X <- data.frame( Group = rep(c("G1","G2"),2:3), Var1 = 1:5, Var2 = 11:15 )
```

which looks like this:

```
   Group Var1 Var2
 1    G1    1   11
 2    G1    2   12
 3    G2    3   13
 4    G2    4   14
 5    G2    5   15
```

Further suppose that we have a (potentially expensive) function

```
f <- function(v)
{
   cat( "Calling f with vector", v, "\n" )
   ## ...additional bookkeeping and processing...
   mean(v)
}
```

that we would like to apply to each of our variables in each group. Using `dplyr`, we might go about it in the following way:

```
X %>% group_by( Group ) %>% summarise_each( funs(f) )
```

However, the output shows that `f` was called one additional time for each variable in G1:

```
Calling f with vector 1 2 
Calling f with vector 1 2 
Calling f with vector 3 4 5 
Calling f with vector 11 12 
Calling f with vector 11 12 
Calling f with vector 13 14 15 
# A tibble: 2 x 3
   Group  Var1  Var2
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> 
1     G1   1.5  11.5
2     G2   4.0  14.0
```

The same issue is present when using `summarize`:

```
> X %>% group_by( Group ) %>% summarise( test = f(Var1) )
Calling f with vector 1 2
Calling f with vector 1 2
Calling f with vector 3 4 5
# A tibble: 2 × 2
   Group  test
  <fctr> <dbl>
1     G1   1.5
2     G2   4.0
```

Why is this happening and how would one go about preventing `summarise` and `summarise_each` from making those extra calls?

(This is using `R` version 3.3.0 and `dplyr` version 0.5.0)

**EDIT:** It appears that the issue has to do with the interplay between `group_by` and `summarise`/`summarise_each`. Without the grouping, no extra calls are made. Also, `mutate` and `mutate_each` do not suffer from this issue. (Credit: [eddi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817778/eddi) and [eipi10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496488/eipi10) for these findings)

Comment: you can narrow it down further - the issue is in `summarise` (and `group_by`)

Comment: I'm actually leaning towards the issue being with `group_by`. Doing a simple `X %>% summarise( test = f(Var1) )` behaves as expected, but `X %>% group_by( Group ) %>% summarise( test = f(Var1) )` does not.

Comment: `mutate` and `mutate_each` don't suffer from this bug (when used with `group_by`)

Comment: But if you group_by and then mutate or mutate_each, there's no extra function call, so it seems related to summarise/summarise_each, but only when using group_by

Comment: The code is [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/summarise.cpp), but I can't quite parse what's happening. I think the extra call per variable might be a result of how it tries to figure out if it can do more in C/C++, but that's a guess.

Comment: And a workaround: `purrr::dmap` doesn't have this issue and respects grouping: `X %>% group_by(Group) %>% purrr::dmap(f)`

Comment: From the code alistaire linked to, we can see that `summarise_impl` calls `summarise_grouped` for grouped data.frames, and calls `summarise_not_grouped` otherwise.  So the extra call is certainly due to some difference between those two functions.  I'm not sure exactly where, though.

Comment: shouldn't this go in the dplyr bug tracker?

Comment: Hmm, I see the error when running dplyr version 0.5.0, but not when I build from the source on GitHub.  So I guess it's been fixed... although I'm not really sure what changed.

Comment: I feel a bit silly for having taken the time to track down the exact commit where it was fixed, but I did it.  See answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this issue is still present in dplyr 0.5.0 (published 2016-06-24), it is fixed in the dplyr GitHub repro.  It was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/c3a2e49b7a33f38df978537c06e8796c9d0c18c1#diff-816c477e576682fdf4dba63791903a3f) made on 2016-09-24.  I've confirmed that I can reproduce the issue when I checkout and build the version at the previous commit, but not when building from that one or subsequent ones.

(And yes, I tried a whole bunch of other ones before I found it. Why I go to such lengths in hope of earning imaginary internet points, I leave as a question for my therapist. :)

In particular, in the function `SEXP process_data(const Data& gdf)` in `inst/include/dplyr/Result/CallbackProcessor.h`, note these changes:

```
  CLASS* obj = static_cast<CLASS*>(this);
  typename Data::group_iterator git = gdf.group_begin();

  RObject first_result = obj->process_chunk(*git);
  ++git; // This line was added
```

and

```
  for (int i = 1; i < ngroups; ++git, ++i) { // changed from starting at i = 0
    RObject chunk = obj->process_chunk(*git);
```

[Comments added by me, not part of the actual source]